# PayPal dropdown menu not working in BootStrap modal window

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, paypal, bootstrap-modal

So I have used the PayPal button generator to create a button that when I test in a vanilla html page works fine like here:

http://www.global-travelpics.com/test/testpaypal.html

However, when embedded in a modal popup in this BootStrap site, it does not behave properly:

http://www.global-travelpics.com/test/ (click Shop then ANTIGUA #1) The Add to cart button is there but only the first of the drop down items appears and I'm at a loss as to why.

Here is the chunk of code making up the form:

```
    <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@aol.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Antigua #1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="A1">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Available sizes">Available sizes</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="A4 Framed Gloss">A4 Framed Gloss £25.00 GBP</option>
    <option value="A4 Framed Canvas">A4 Framed Canvas £35.00 GBP</option>
    <option value="A4 Framed Stretched Pine">A4 Framed Stretched Pine £45.00 GBP</option>
    <option value="A3 Framed Gloss">A3 Framed Gloss £45.00 GBP</option>
    <option value="A3 Framed Canvas">A3 Framed Canvas £50.00 GBP</option>
    <option value="A3 Framed Stretched">A3 Framed Stretched £65.00 GBP</option>
    <option value="A2 Framed Gloss">A2 Framed Gloss £65.00 GBP</option>
    <option value="A2 Framed Canvas">A2 Framed Canvas £70.00 GBP</option>
    <option value="A2 Framed Stretched Pine">A2 Framed Stretched Pine £75.00 GBP</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="A4 Framed Gloss">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="25.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="A4 Framed Canvas">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="35.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="A4 Framed Stretched Pine">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="45.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select3" value="A3 Framed Gloss">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount3" value="45.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select4" value="A3 Framed Canvas">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount4" value="50.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select5" value="A3 Framed Stretched">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount5" value="65.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select6" value="A2 Framed Gloss">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount6" value="65.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select7" value="A2 Framed Canvas">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount7" value="70.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select8" value="A2 Framed Stretched Pine">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount8" value="75.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: The rest are there too, if you hover on the list. the color black for font is being overwritten somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I'll work out where that is occurring or apply some new css

Comment: no problem, glad that helped